# Multithreading problems

Tags: java, multithreading, minecraft

I'm trying get more into multithreading in Java, but my endeavors have been stopped at this code:

```
package io.nlaz.test.commands;

import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.command.TabExecutor;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import java.util.List;

public class test implements TabExecutor {
        @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        try {
            Thread a24 = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    sender.sendMessage("2");
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    sender.sendMessage("4");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            Thread a35 = new Thread(() -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    sender.sendMessage("3");
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    sender.sendMessage("5");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            sender.sendMessage("1");
            a24.start();
            a35.start();
        } catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> onTabComplete(CommandSender sender, Command command, String alias, String[] args) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

When the code is run, it supposed to send a message counting up to 5 every second. but when run it get's up to 2, then waits for the a24 thread to finish, then executes a35. I've looked up possible solutions to this, however they all either lead to the main thread getting paused, or the exact same problem as I already have.

I do have a part of it might be because I'm using `Thread.sleep()` and not something like `Thread.currentThread().wait()`. However when I use that method, I get an error saying `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException: current thread is not owner`. Any suggestions help, thank you!

Comment: a24 takes ~3s to complete. a35 waits 3s before starting. Not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: [1] the app is doing exactly what you said it should: a24 finishes before a35 starts because a24's code literally runs that fast (and a35 waits that long before doing anything visible). [2] wait() is a thing that works in tandem with notify() and is a primitive thread synchronization mechanism. It is nothing at all to do with 'I want to wait X milliseconds before continuing'. That's what `pause` is for.

Comment: I get that the code is doing what I'm telling it to do, but what I *want* it to do is run both a24 and a35 at the same time, and not wait on each other. I'm just asking if there even is a way to do this, and if anyone can point me in the right direction to figuring it out

Answer (score 0):

Do **NOT** use `Thread` with Bukkit's plugins. Spigot has his own threading system.

```java
BukkitTask task = Bukkit.getScheduler().runTaskTimer(myPlugin, new Runnable() {
   private int timer = 4;

   @Override
   public void run() {
      if(timer == 4 || timer ==2) {
          sender.sendMessage("Time: " + timer);
      }
      if(timer == 0) {
          task.cancel();
      }
      timer--;
   }
});
```

[Documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitScheduler.html)